# Huge space when there image is blocked in Outlook 2000, 2002, 2003, 2011 email clients

Tags: html, image, email, outlook

I’m currently testing my emails and in the header of my email I show an image. It’s not a `background-image`, it’s the `img` tag. This image is only about 177px in height. I’ve set the height on the `img` tag itself and the surrounding `table`. So my markup looks like so:

```
<!-- // Begin Template Banner \\ -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" height="177">
    <tr>
        <td valign="bottom">
            <img src="img.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="177" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- // End Template Banner \\ -->
```

When I test in Litmus and see that my header image is blocked, Outlook seems to add a big massive space (see image below). My actual header image is only sixth of the size in the image so I don’t know why Outlook adds all this extra space?? Anybody encountered this problem before or can anybody propose a solution?

[image: Massive space added by Outlook]

Thanks.

Comment: This also happens in the latest version of Ymail

Answer (score 1):

The solution that I found for this is to not have a height set on the table.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
    <tr>
        <td valign="bottom">
          <img src="img.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="177" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I was having this same problem with images on an HTML email that I was working on myself. I am using Litmus.

Hopefully this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I’ve since removed these images from the top of the emails but if I use them again I will be sure to try out your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You skipped the the [ALT text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Alternative_text_for_images), just add it and the image placeholder will go away.

Hope that helps.